# Cassandra Trigger java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra

Hey i try to do the first steps with Casssandra trigger. The trigger should only get the mutation and write it to a simple .txt file nothing more nothing less.
Everytime i do an isert i get the following Error:
**java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.cassandra.triggers.invertedindex.augment(Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/partitions/Partition;)Ljava/util/Collection**

The code is from a example i found in the internet.

```
public class invertedindex implements ITrigger
```

{
   // private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(invertedindex.class);
    private Properties properties = loadProperties();
    //private Object array;

```
public void augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update) throws IOException
{


        PrintWriter pWriter = null; 
        //long millis2;

       // List<RowMutation> mutations = new ArrayList<>();

        String indexKeySpace = properties.getProperty("keyspace");
        String indexColumnFamily = properties.getProperty("table");
        for (IColumn cell : update)
        {
            // Skip the row marker and other empty values, since they lead to an empty key.
            if (cell.value().remaining() > 0)
            {
                pWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log_trigger_test.txt",true)));
                RowMutation mutation = new RowMutation(indexKeySpace, cell.value());
               // mutation.add(properties.getProperty("columnfamily"), cell.name(), cell.value(), System.currentTimeMillis();
               // mutations.add(mutation);
               // mutation.addColumnOrSuperColumn(arg0, arg1);
                //System.out.println((mutation.toString()));
                pWriter.println((mutation.toString()));

            }
        }
        pWriter.close();
       // return mutations;

    }

private static Properties loadProperties()
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    InputStream stream = invertedindex.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("invertedindex.properties");
    try
    {
        properties.load(stream);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        FileUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
    }

    return properties;
}
```

}

What i am doing wrong here? And is there more information about Casssandra trigger anywere? I only found some old stuff?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Cassandra 3.x but have written a trigger for pre-3.x. Your trigger should be implementing the:

```
    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update);
```

method.

Take a look at the trigger example [here](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/triggers) for how to implement a 3.x trigger.

Comment: This is very useful but do you know with the new 3.x way to fetch all the modified cells/columns?